# Get the Current Page Number

Tags: posts, pages

In a situation where one has 20 posts per page. I would like to get the current page number in order to make some nice page links at the bottom. How do you get the current page. I tried this

```
<?php echo '(Page '.$page.' of '.$numpages.')'; ?>
```

and it just says page 1 of 1 on every page.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When WordPress is using pagination like this, there's a query variable `$paged` that it keys on.  So page 1 is `$paged=1` and page 15 is `$paged=15`.

You can get the value of this variable with the following code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Getting the total number of pages is a bit trickier.  First you have to count all the posts in the database.  Then filter by which posts are published (versus which are drafts, scheduled, trash, etc.).  *Then* you have to divide this count by the number of posts you expect to appear on each page:

```
$total_post_count = wp_count_posts();
$published_post_count = $total_post_count->publish;
$total_pages = ceil( $published_post_count / $posts_per_page );
```

I haven't tested this yet, but you might need to fetch `$posts_per_page` the same way you fetched `$paged` (using `get_query_var()`).

Comment: Why not use `$wp_query->max_num_pages`?

Comment: That's a sound alternative. Part of `$wp_query` I completely forgot was there :-/

Comment: @EAMann BTW: there is also `found_posts` property "The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters", wp_count_posts() is kind of an overhead.

Answer (score 9):

You could do it with a single line of code, but then again, you might want to add the code in other places, so a function is usually more useful.

```
function current_paged( $var = '' ) {
    if( empty( $var ) ) {
        global $wp_query;
        if( !isset( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) )
            return;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    }
    else {
        global $$var;
            if( !is_a( $$var, 'WP_Query' ) )
                return;
        if( !isset( $$var->max_num_pages ) || !isset( $$var ) )
            return;
        $pages = absint( $$var->max_num_pages );
    }
    if( $pages < 1 )
        return;
    $page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    echo 'Page ' . $page . ' of ' . $pages;
}
```

**NOTE:** Code can go into your functions file.

Simply call the function where you want to show the "Page x of y" message, eg.

```
<?php current_paged(); ?>
```

If you need the code to work with a custom query, ie. one you've created using `WP_Query`, then simply pass along the name of the variable that holds the query to the function.

**Example non-existant query:**

```
$fred = new WP_Query;
$fred->query();
if( $fred->have_posts() ) 
... etc..
```

Getting the current page for the custom query using the function posted earlier..

```
<?php current_paged( 'fred' ); ?>
```

If you want to just totally forget the custom query support and you're looking for a one-liner, then this should do it..

```
<?php echo 'Page '. ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) . ' of ' . $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>
```

Hope that helps.. :)

Comment: If I were you I'd check if `$var` is a query: `if( is_a( $var, 'WP_Query' ) )` will return true if it's a query object.

Comment: Yes, that's actually a very sensible idea, done!.

Answer (score 1):

From wordpress documentation `paginate_links( string|array $args = '' )`:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
 
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
 
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

This will list the page numbers and Next post, and Previous post. You need to post this link on the pages where you want the page numbers to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above - a simpler way to get the max number of pages is with:

```php
global $wp_query

$wp_query->max_num_pages
```

Answer (score 0):

One option that works on all my archive pages is this:

```
$paged_maxnum = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages;

if ( $paged_maxnum > 1 ) {

    $paged_current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $title_page_nrs = 'page nr ' . $paged_current_page . ' of ' . $paged_maxnum;

    echo '<title>' . get_the_archive_title( '', false ) . ' - ' . $title_page_nrs . ' | Your Website Name</title>';

} else {

    echo '<title>' . get_the_archive_title( '', false ) . ' | Your Website Name</title>'; 

}
```

First query if there is more than one page in this `wp_query`, then concatenate title with current page via `$paged_current_page` and total pages with `$title_page_nrs`. Lastly `echo` it. If above 1 page first, then `else` if is not paged. This goes into my archive.php or templates for this type. It produces:

`<title>Taxonomy title - page nr 1 of 4 | Your Website Name</title>`

or

`<title>Taxonomy title | Your Website Name</title>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
```