# Conditonal tag or work around to identify page number of pagnation

Tags: conditional-tags

I use a set of conditionals to define metatags on the various parts of my site. I noted that all pagination pages use the same metatags. If I can use a conditional tag or work around to identify the page number then I can use this to define unique metatags for each page of pagination.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12372/get-the-current-page-number

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

to get current page number

Comment: My usage will be in a switch: `switch ($paged){case 1: do something; break;case 2: do something else; break;default: something else; break;}` Should your code for $paged work for returning case 1-25 or whatever?

Comment: I will test it and let you know.